# not able to insert data in table using datatable

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, datatable

i have one table having 3 rows and i am trying to insert data into first two rows using data table but it is inserting data like this , instead of inserting in first two row it is inserting in other rows

```
                 price  qty  total
                --------------------
                  5     10    -

                  5     12    -

                  -      -    50

                  -      -    60
```

but i wants

```
                 price  qty  total
                --------------------
                  5     10    50

                  5     12    60
```

i have used following code for selecting data from table than inserting data into table,it is showing data correctly but just inserting in wrong rows

```
 int sp;
public DataTable bind1()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("cnnection");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [order]", con);      
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt;
}
public DataTable bind2()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("cnnection");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [order](total) values(@total)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", sp);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt;
}    
 public void gbind()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = bind1();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("total");
        dt1.Columns.Add(dc);        
        foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
           {
            int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(drow["price"]);
            int s2 = Convert.ToInt16(drow["qty"]);
            int s3 = s1 * s2;
            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["total"] = s3;
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
            }           
         foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
             string s1 = row["total"].ToString();
             for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                sp = Convert.ToInt16(s1);
                dt = bind2();
              }
            }
```

i have tried like this also but still same problem

```
public void gbind()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = bind1();       
        foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
        {
            int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(drow["price"]);
            int s2 = Convert.ToInt16(drow["qty"]);
            int s3 = s1 * s2;                    
            drow["total"] = s3;
            sp = s3;
            dt = bind2();            
        }
     }
```

Comment: What are the Three rows you have in you table before doing the INSERT ??

Comment: i think u need to use update instead of insert

Answer (score 0):

In your forEach loop in the gbind method, I don't think you should be adding a new row for "total", it would need to be a column. And dt1.Rows.Add(dr) should be dt1.Columns.Add(dr). Try rewriting your code to add a column instead. Let me know if that helps any.

Comment: its another datatable dt1,and i am adding row in its column ,and than trying to insert that rows data to datatable dt

Answer (score 0):

Comment these two lines in your code. Remove the code to add extra rows. You just need to update the column value.

```
foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
           {
            int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(drow["price"]);
            int s2 = Convert.ToInt16(drow["qty"]);
            int s3 = s1 * s2;
            //DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["total"] = s3;
            //dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

Comment: still nothing,and i am adding row in column of another datatable dt1 which need copy its row in datatable dt